# EasyCap Capture card works with Wii, not with PS2

Tags: windows-8, video-capture, capture, wii, playstation

I ordered an EasyCap capture card a while ago, and I'm not sure which model. It only has the RCA cables, no S-Video. Anyway, on both ULead(which I got on the Internet, something else entirely was on the CD it came with), and Open Broadcast Studio, it takes video from my Wii just fine, but when I plug in my PS2, I get a blue screen, sometimes with a little greenish bar at the top that wiggles up and down a bit. I get the same blue screen, albeit w/o the green bar, when the easycap is turned on, but nothing is plugged into it.
I'm running 64-bit Windows 8, and like I said, the Wii works with it. Is this an issue with the EasyCap, the PS2, my PC, anything that can be fixed? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Without more information about the device its hard to say.

Comment: Well, it didn't come with a whole lot of information. It's an easycap card, USB connection, black case, green LED, red/yellow/white RCA cables. Shows up on the computer as USB Component I believe in the Device Manager, and as USB 2.0 Camera or something similar under OBS and ULead

Answer (score 0):

The PS2 supports interlaced scan(720x240 at 60fps) for most games, whereas the Wii supports progressive scan(720x480 at 30fps).

Make sure there is a tick in the box 'Allow access to capture device's settings'. Also make sure the PS2 is not using component cables.

**References**

- [USB 2.0 Video Capture Device
  Quick Installation Guide(pdf)](http://www.siig.com/media/files/manuals/0008/04-0561c.pdf)
- [How do you make a NTSC interlaced DVD video progressive?](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/363675-How-do-you-make-a-NTSC-interlaced-DVD-video-progressive)
- [Video Streams as Sources for Files](http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/content/video_source.shtml)
- [10 Best Video Game Recorders](http://heavy.com/games/2014/05/top-10-best-video-game-recorders-capture-devices-hd/)